# Facebook page owner

Tags: facebook-pages

I'm trying to set up my business page on the business ad manager account. It says on there that "Your request for access is pending"

I went on my Facebook page to check who the owner is and it says 'TC Giveaways'

But I'm wondering if anyone knows how I would need to accept the request or change the owner to myself?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I have access to both FB Business and the Page; I'm simply trying to connect the two. Been waiting weeks to see a request notification.